# I know I am missing a rotor but I don't know what to attach it to

Tags: disc-brake, rotor

I got a cheap second hand bike for my son as its not worth repairing his current one as he outgrew it. At the time, I knew it needed a new inner tube which I was going to replace.

Only now I noticed that the front brakes don't work. I can see they are disc brakes but the disc is missing. The only disc I can get locally has mounting holes. The bike has nowhere to mount it to. The calipers? open and close just fine.

I thought about changing the brakes to the type that works against the rim but the problem is the same and there is nowhere to mount those brakes (holes are missing and I don't want to make them)

[image: Center of the rim with no where to install rotor]
[image: Disc brake assembly with working calipers]
[image: forks]

<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

Assuming I can install a disc rotor do I need to get a specific kind or *something* else to mount it to? Do I actually need a different rim?

Comment: Someone replaced the front wheel with one designed for rim brakes.

Comment: Noted that the wheel's axle has nuts.  That's unusual for a disk brake bike, and suggests the wheel is older than the bike.  Do you have any working front brakes at all ?

Comment: I assume this was a private sale.  In many countries selling a bike without 2 functioning brakes is illegal as well as dangerous, and the seller could be prosecuted.  There's not much chance of action being taken unless against a shop that makes a habit of it, but it might be worth checking the laws where you are

Comment: @Criggie I have another set of rim brakes but the require mounting holes in the forks that this bike does not have. This is not a "high end" bike so none of this was really expected

Comment: @ChrisH I am curious to see if there is anything covering this scenario. Useless in my case since the seller moved away and I am not going to try and fight it.

Comment: @Matt on a cheap 2nd hand runabout I'd do the same sort of thing - buy it, check it over, and deal with anything I find. It's possible that this bike was "fixed" for use in a flat area - where I work I see people riding with one or even both bikes disconnected because the wheels are so out of true, but not on hills.  Further thought - it could have been stolen: 1 person locked their bike up by the front wheel only, and the rest of the bike was taken, to have another wheel bodged on to it.

Comment: Seeing the latest picture, I thought maybe the fork had been swapped, but no: [that bike was sold with front disc/rear rim brakes](https://www.policeauctionscanada.com/Listing/Details/47784438/Supercycle-Ascent-21Speed-DS-Front-Disc-Bike-236756D) and white forks on a black frame

Comment: That fork seems to have two mounts for cantilevers/V brakes on the sides, and a single top hole potentially for a caliper brake though realistically it would be best for a fender/mudguard not a brake,  (edit - this was incorrect, sorry)

Comment: @Criggie Not an expert by any means but the fork frame _looks_ like it should support those brakes.. The v-brakes on all my other bikes require on the bottoms of the "horseshoe" that this one doesnt have. Perhaps this fork was used for multiple models and only certain ones were tapped.

Comment: @Criggie I think the top hole on the fork may be for a white front reflector.

Comment: @Criggie The wheel having nuts is part for the course for a Supercycle. This is a decades-famous garbage bicycle brand from the Canadian Tire store chain. If you look at the [original pic](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/supercycle-ascent-full-suspension-mountain-bike-26-in-0711038p.html) you see nuts.

Comment: I can't see the other side of the front wheel - is there any chance it's been put in the wrong way round (without a rotor, but with mounting for the rotor on the wrong side of the forks)?

Comment: @user7761803 I reckon you'd be able to see the flange of a 6-bolt hub looking through the wheel

Comment: @Kaz I paid ~10CAD$ for it (Used it as a bargaining chip to get a drill at the same time. Drill is great). I know its crap but like hell I am getting a decent bike for my son who is just going to throw it on the ground everywhere he goes.

Comment: @Matt when there are several similar models, manufacturers can do funny things - my hybrid has a disc-compatible frame but not forks, and came with V-brakes.  The next model up used the same frame and had discs.  But here I'm sure it's a different wheel

Comment: I assume you got the original receipt for the drill.

Comment: @ojs No. This is just a neighbors garage sale. I accepted the risk of my actions.

Comment: Ok, in that case the neighbor should know what happened to the front wheel. I'm just personally a bit peeved because the building I live in has been broken into a few times and power tools are always the first thing to be stolen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need a wheel with a hub that is rotor compatible and fits your bike.

There are two main ways to mount a disk brake rotor to the hub.

A Shimano centerlock design has splines on the hub to allow a rotor to be attached.
[image]

Or a six bolt rotor mount
[image]

Your front hub does not have either of these mounting methods. If the fork is original to the bike then it is likely that the wheel is not.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can see, there is no serrated ring and the hub is not a disc-brake compatible one (for either center lock or 6-bolt rotors). Thus, for disc brakes you'll need a new wheel that mounts one or the other style of rotor. The rotor will cost probably an extra $20 or so if the wheel doesn't come with one.

It's hard to tell from the photos, but your wheel *may* have the flat surface next to the rim needed for V-brakes (pics, please). As you note, the issue is then mounting rim brakes.

We'd need photos of the whole fork, especially of the front just below the "crown" area where the Y of legs starts. If you have brake mounting bosses there, or threaded holes for them, it should be quite straightforward to mount V brakes. Decent quality Shimano V brakes run about $15-20 online in the US.

PS - I'm assuming this bike is a 26" wheel mountain bike - it would be good to know the wheel size for sure.

PPS - As wheels can be fairly expensive, in the past I have been known to buy a cheap used bike just for the wheels and then resell the frame.

Update: Thanks for the bike photo! It does seem to be a Walmart-level bike ( https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/supercycle-ascent-full-suspension-mountain-bike-26-in-0711038p.html ) and with no mounting holes for V brake bosses as you mentioned, I think you're stuck with buying a 26" wheel with disc brake hub and rotor. On the good side, a decent front wheel will make for safer riding and stand up to disc braking forces, and you can always keep it or sell it once your son outgrows this bike.

Comment: I've also been known to buy cheap 2nd hand bikes for wheels - but back wheels with rim brakes.  Disc brakes tend to be on newer and/higher end (i.e. more expensive 2nd hand) bikes, and front wheels are cheaper new than back ones

Comment: Pick of forks attached.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately the brake is a cable-actuated non-hydraulic brake and you don't need to worry about fluid loss in this case. The hub looks as if it might have a lock-ring for the disk (that serrated ring on the left next to the spokes), but I'm not so sure when looking at the blown-up picture. In which case you'd need a new front wheel, unfortunately.

If there is a lock-ring, all you'd need is a fitting centre-lock brake disc, probably a 160mm version and a lock-ring tool. Both are quite inexpensive. It's not rocket science to install it and there is a number of how to videos on YouTube. Check the brake pads as they could be missing as well or be in a poor shape and adjust them.

Comment: That looks to be a Walmart-level el-cheapo wheel. I‘ll eat my dropper post if that hub actually has a centerlock interface.

Comment: @MaplePanda's right - there aren't any actual splines, and the part that looks like a bit splines gets too close to the spokes